# EF Core: SaveChanges() error when exactly 167 records

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

The following is the log output from the `DbContext`:

```
13:48:54.572 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.572 RelationalEventId.BatchReadyForExecution[20700] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
13:48:54.574 [1]        Executing 41 update commands as a batch.
13:48:54.575 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.575 RelationalEventId.CommandCreating[20103] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
13:48:54.577 [1]        Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader'.
13:48:54.577 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.577 RelationalEventId.CommandCreated[20104] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
13:48:54.579 [1]        Created DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (2ms).
13:48:54.580 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.580 RelationalEventId.CommandInitialized[20106] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
13:48:54.582 [1]        Initialized DbCommand for 'ExecuteReader' (5ms).
13:48:54.583 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.583 RelationalEventId.CommandExecuting[20100] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
13:48:54.584 [1]        Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='86400']
13:48:54.586 [1]
13:48:54.587 [1]  fail: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.587 RelationalEventId.CommandError[20102] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command)
13:48:54.589 [1]        Failed executing DbCommand (4ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='86400']
13:48:54.591 [1]
13:48:54.602 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.602 RelationalEventId.TransactionDisposed[20204] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction)
13:48:54.604 [1]        Disposing transaction.
13:48:54.605 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.605 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosing[20002] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
13:48:54.607 [1]        Closing connection to database 'vp_mar5' on server 'localhost'.
13:48:54.609 [1]  dbug: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.609 RelationalEventId.ConnectionClosed[20003] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection)
13:48:54.611 [1]        Closed connection to database 'vp_mar5' on server 'localhost' (3ms).
13:48:54.618 [1]  fail: 3/6/2024 13:48:54.618 CoreEventId.SaveChangesFailed[10000] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update)
13:48:54.619 [1]        An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'VisionPlai.VPDatabaseContext'.
13:48:54.621 [1]        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
13:48:54.624 [1]         ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.
13:48:54.625 [1]           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)
13:48:54.627 [1]           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)
13:48:54.628 [1]           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex)
13:48:54.629 [1]           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean execAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
13:48:54.632 [1]           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
13:48:54.633 [1]           at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
13:48:54.634 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
13:48:54.637 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
13:48:54.639 [1]           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
13:48:54.640 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
13:48:54.641 [1]           at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.MySQLModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)
13:48:54.644 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
13:48:54.646 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
13:48:54.647 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
13:48:54.649 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
13:48:54.651 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__112_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)
13:48:54.653 [1]           at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.MySQLExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
13:48:54.656 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
13:48:54.658 [1]           at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
```

For this call to `SaveChanges()`, there are many other log entries in the form of

```
12:23:59.077 [1]        Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[@p0='2023-12-27T00:00:05.5120000' (DbType = DateTime), @p1='1061', @p2='11603' (Nullable = true), @p3='3', 
12:23:59.725 [1]        INSERT INTO `PlayData` (`date_time`, `playerId`, `Sessionid`, `agentId`, ...
12:23:59.739 [1]        VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12 ...
```

that are all executed properly. In each of these, the `[Parameters=[...]]` is followed by SQL (inserts, updates, etc). However, on the step causing the error, there is no SQL following the empty parameters `[Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='86400']` .

The `SaveChanges` has a single new "Session" record that is inserted into the database. That session has 167 child records in a simple collection.

If I REMOVE any one or a few of the 167 child records, `SaveChanges()` works perfectly.

So long as I remove at least one record, I can add a few more records (tested up to 20) and the `SaveChanges()` works fine.

At timestamp `13:48:54.574` the log indicates that it will update 41 records, but then at timestamp `13:48:54.584` the `DbCommand` does not contain an UPDATE statement.

Some of the 167 records are updated and some are inserted. Whether  the removed record is updated or inserted doesn't matter- removing one of either makes `SaveChanges()` work

Why does arbitrarily changing the count of records resolve the error?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big (# of columns and size of text columns) is this entity being updated? EF Core will use a default batch size of 42, (since EF Core 5) however if your tables are particularly large in terms of # of columns and length of things like VARCHAR columns this may need to be tweaked downwards to avoid overruns if you have very large tables being updated.

You can decrease the batch size using in the DbContext `.OnConfiguring()`:

```
.MinBatchSize(1)
.MaxBatchSize(30));
```

For instance to drop the maximum statements in a batch to 30. Some testing may be necessary to find a "safe" level based on the worst tables, or disable it entirely. (`MaxBatchSize(1)`)

The typical culprit for issues like this where large tables are necessary is using the `Update()` method on the DbContext instead of leveraging the change tracking.  When you use `context.Update(entity)` EF core generates an `UPDATE` statement for every property in the entity, regardless of whether than property actually changed or not. Instead, when updating a set of entities, you are better off reading those entities from the DbContext with tracking enabled (by default) then copy the values across from the detached copies of entities that you were normally passing into the `Update` calls. The change tracker will then generate `UPDATE` statements for the entities and only the properties that have actually changed. This will result in much shorter `UPDATE` statements that won't overflow the statement length limit of the database. This is often overlooked in favour of trying to avoid an extra read from the database, but that read also serves a purpose of validating that the entities about to be updated are actually present, and ensures that only values you intend to actually update are altered. `Update(entity)` can make your system (particularly web applications) vulnerable to data tampering.

Comment: thank you! That was it. I lowered the batch size and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Just keep in mind that could be a temporary solution if you have potentially larger tables with more/larger columns. I do recommend checking if you are using `Update()` on the DbContext and consider re-factoring that to reduce the size of batch updates, allowing more records to be updated in a batch and overall improving performance with less SQL text being composed, sent over the wire, and unnecessarily updating fields that do not change.